# Simpler Way of Creating Lists from other Lists

Tags: python

I have 3 lists: x, y, and z. All are the same size, but I need to create new lists of x, y, and z, depending on the value at each index of z, as shown below:

```
xNew = []
yNew = []
zNew = []
i = 0
for value in z:
    if value > 0:
        xNew.append(x[i])
        yNew.append(y[i])
        zNew.append(z[i])
    i += 1
```

Does anyone know if there is a tidier, perhaps even more efficient, way of performing the above computation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the most straightforward way:

```
it = zip(x, y, z)
xnew, ynew, znew = zip(*(t for t in it if t[-1] > 0))
```

We use [the `zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) twice to restore the original structure of the data.

---

`zip(x, y, z)` creates a new iterator object, which yields triples.

`(t for t in it if t[-1] > 0)` filters triples (`t[-1]` is the `value`).

`zip(*(...))` yields exactly 3 tuples and `xnew`, `ynew` and `znew` receive them.

Comment: Kudos for the one liner, but this is not very pleasant to read as the list comprehension unfortunately (+1 anyway)

Comment: Asked for the tidiest so I guess this wins! It works. Could you explain what t[-1] is in a little detail? As in, what t is exactly and why you use -1.

Comment: @alwaysboots `t` is a 3-tuple:  `(element_from_x, element_from_y, element_from_z)`. `t[-1]` accesses the last element of the tuple which is the `element_from_z`.

Comment: @vaultah Could t[2] have been used instead then?

Comment: @alwaysboots Yes. I just tried to make it obvious that we're accessing the last element of the tuple... You can even use unpacking: `... for x_value, y_value, z_value in it ...` and then check the condition: `z_value > 0`, but this is unnecessarily verbose.

Answer (score 1):

Not more efficient but a bit tidier:

```
for (_x,_y,_z) in zip(x,y,z):
    if _z > 0:
        l.append((_x, _y,_z))
x,y,z = map(list, zip(*l))

print(x,y,z)
```

For a different approach using itemgetter:

```
from operator import itemgetter
inds = [ind for ind, value in enumerate(z)if value > 0]
x,y,z = (list(itemgetter(*inds)(l)) for l in (x,y,z))
print(x,y,z)
```

Comment: Why not use `zip()` to include the `x`, `y` and `z` values in the loop?

Comment: @MartijnPieters, yes but Valutah got there first

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehensions (used as filters) in conjunction with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
>>> z=[1,1,-1,1,1,-1]

>>> x=[1,2,3,4,5,6]

>>> xNew=[x[i] for i,zi in enumerate(z) if zi>0]
>>> xNew
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Or with [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) is even more beautiful:

```
>>> xNew=[xi for xi,zi in zip(x,z) if zi>0]
>>> xNew
[1, 2, 4, 5]
```

Comment: I know. What I means was: You might want to also handle `y` in your answer, so that it matches the question. (Not every reader might be aware that [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) takes an arbitrary number of arguments)

Comment: No. For `yNew` you have to copy that line and replace x with y

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit complicated, since you have several lists and need to skip values in all of the lists based on a value from one of them. Here's the best way, I think, using `zip` and list comprehensions:

```
xNew, yNew, zNew = zip(*(xyz for xyz in zip(x, y, z) if xyz[2] > 0))
```